# $( document ).on( "click", not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, document-ready

this is the first time I post on Stack Overflow so here I go.

This is the HTML code I'm trying to work with jQuery / AJAX, I got a DIV with all the purchase options inside, 3 buttons / forms with the different options available and the AJAX call to load more items with their respective purchase buttons and options with the same HTML formatting.

```
<div class="purchase_options">
    <form class="purchbox" method="post">
        <a class="purchase1" href="#">$24.95</a>
        <a class="text">MP3</a>
    </form>

    <form class="purchbox" method="post">
        <a class="purchase2" href="#">$39.95</a>
        <a class="text">WAV</a>
    </form>

    <form class="purchbox" method="post">
        <a class="purchase3" href="#">$99.95</a>
        <a class="text">Premium</a>
    </form>

    <a href="#">LOAD MORE</a>
</div>
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that with the following function everything works perfectly, no matter if I click on the links, the text, the form as is, the function will be executed.

**Snippet 1**

```
(function($) {
$('.purchbox').on('click', function () {
    //CODE
    });
;
}(jQuery));
```

But in order to add the event to AJAX dynamically loaded content you gotta link those events inside *(document).ready* and *$(document).on("click")* like in the following example.

**Snippet 2**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( document ).on( "click", ".purchbox", function() {
        //CODE
    } );
});
```

And it works really, but it only works if you click in the form object as is, if you click in the hyperlinks, paragraphs or whatever that is inside that form then the function will not be executed. I made a deep research in the subject but I can't find a working solution.

To show the problem in a more graphic way I've attached an image of the clickable areas that execute the function in both snippets.

**Snippet 1**

[image]

(No matter where you click the code will be executed)

**Snippet 2**

[image]

(If you click in the blue sections the code will not be executed and I don't get why, but if you click in the ''.purchbox'' form as is then it will)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/vshgy8qe/ Can you come up with a [MCVE]? If the CSS is relevant, can you post it as well? Also note that if you use event delegation, you don't need to wait for `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` to attach. Also, neither `MP3 LEASE` nor `MP3` are in the HTML you posted..?

Comment: @Surce what is you actual problem, where do you want to trigger your click event ? You are calling you event on `.purchbox` so everything inside this class will capture the click event.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your binding. From the sound of it, something bound on the blue marked areas stops bubbling (`.stopPropagation()` or `.stopImmediatePropagation()`). Find what and either remove the stop or call your script, whatever makes sense in your code.

Comment: To be more exact: your binding executes some code whenever a `click` event is fired on a `.purchbox` element. Inside your `.purchbox`, some children prevent bubbling of `click` event and the event never gets to `.purchbox`, because it does not leave the child. This is not default behavior. There must be some code in your app explicitly preventing the bubbling and you need to find out what and where.